# Warning/Error messages from javascript Selenium chrome webdriver in node for webview

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome, webview

I am using the chrome webdriver to connect to chrome webview for an embedded app.

The below code does instantiate a working driver object, where I can query for elements and send keys.  However when I initiate the driver I get the error messages (show below) in the console.

I would like to be able to address the errors/warnings or at least suppress them, as it is causing readability issues in the output of my testing.

code:

```
import { Builder, By, WebDriver } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { Options } from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';

async function loadWebDriver(): Promise<boolean> {
    const chromeOptions = new Options();
    chromeOptions.addArguments('--remote-debugging-port=' + REMOTEDUBUG_PORT);
    chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath(WEBVIEWPATH);
    console.log('start driver');
    try {
        driver = await new Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
            .build();
        console.log('end driver');
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

results:

```
start driver
[1113/161206.516:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.517:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.518:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.519:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.520:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.521:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.521:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.522:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.523:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.525:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.525:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.526:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.527:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.527:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.528:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.529:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.530:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.530:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.531:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.532:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.532:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.533:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.534:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.535:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.536:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.537:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.537:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.538:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.539:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.540:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.540:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.542:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.544:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.546:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.547:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.548:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.549:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.557:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.558:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.559:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.562:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.562:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.563:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.563:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(576)] locale resources are not loaded
[1113/161206.572:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(355)] bind() returned an error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (0x2740)
[1113/161206.573:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(294)] Cannot start http server for devtools.
end driver
```

Anyone have an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else experiencing this, It turns out the error with "locale resources are not loaded" come from not having data in the locals directory.  I was able to fix this by passing the path that had the locals files:

```
chromeOptions.addArguments('--locales-dir-path=' + localsPath);
```

I'm still looking into the remaining bottom 2 errors.